# App crashes on iPad device but working on simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, iad

1. I just have device UDID & client reported that the app is crashing
   on his device & he is not able to start application.
2. The client device iOS version is 7.1.2
3. Also i am not having any crash report.(Asked for Crash Report)
4. Now referring
   ([iAd works on simulator but crash on device(ipad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169518/iad-works-on-simulator-but-crash-on-deviceipad)):
   I am assuming the reason behind this might be the library,

[image]

**So will making iAD.framwork optional & handling codes related to this do the trick?**

- **Update:
- Unfortunately the cause of the crash was -[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent which was iOS version fault & not device fault. I got it resolved.  sorry to iAd for blaming or trying to blame. Long live iAd. Thanks**

Comment: You can not rely on this. Assumption will not make it resolve. I suggest you to ask user for crash logs from device.

Comment: Thanks @Kampai.Yes, I have asked for crash log & iOS version but will like to find the reason behind this till then. Hopefully someone might have came across same situation.

Comment: I suggest u take a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/q/6931886/2591052  also I agree with @Kampai you need the crash logs to debug the issue

Comment: @Geet, I appreciate your comment & reference. I am sure the cause given in reference is not the cause for this crash. Thank's

Comment: @Kampai may be you are right, but we cant say anything unless and until we see the logs, however I had encountered the similar issue mentioned in reference

Comment: Have you tested with actual device :) and what is the Error message ?

Comment: Only IPhone devices & No iPAd device.

Comment: Check with actual device and find the error message then, resolve it.

Comment: Dear @Vineesh, ofcource That i will Do. Currently my attempt is just to find someone who came across the same situation or say that No iAd is not the culprit for this. Thanks

Comment: There is no way that this is answerable. It could be a code problem. It could be a certificate problem. The device might be out of space. Out of memory. There's just no way anyone can know.

Comment: Thank's @Stephen, I will update this once i get console logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you need crash details. Without it, nobody help you. 
Integrate any crash reporter SDK: [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com) or anything like this.